# Aggregate Photon behaviour at spooky distances

Tags: quantum-mechanics

**Thought experiment:**

Mars — Spaceship — Earth

Spaceship is steadily positioned perfectly between Mars and Earth, same distance. On the spaceship is a photon entangler that laser-projects each entangled pair in opposite directions to Earth and Mars.
On the surface of Earth and Mars is a phosphor screen. A scientist on Mars has a double-slit mask that his photons travel through before reaching his screen. He sits watching his screen, watching a beautiful wave pattern. Meanwhile, his friend scientist on Earth sees that his Martian friend is not forcing his stream of photons into a classical state, because he sees a steady wave pattern on his screen. He gets bored and wants to send a message to his Martian friend, so he waves his hand back and forth in front of his slit mask in a morse-code-like pattern. He assumes he is collapsing Phi a split second before his friend’s entangled counterparts, because the entangler on the spaceship steadily maintains position at the exact center-point between the 2 slit masks, within a Plank Length margin of error, and the photon path between the planets is remarkably isolated, and they travel safe from decoherence, using magic technology. The Martian scientist notices his screen now flickering from wavey to slit-ey to wavey, etc. So, he starts recording these intervals of pattern change and decodes a message: “Hello from Earth!”, and he replies in a similar manner: “Hi Bob! It’s cold over here!”. Bob reads this reply within seconds, but Mars is several light-minutes away.

How was such spooky communication possible?

Comment: Simple, it is not possible to communicate this way. Forbidden in QFT. You have completely misunderstood what the spooky action at a distance actually claims can be done. It is much less than you think.

Comment: How can you "watch a beautiful wave pattern" without having the photons interact with something (a screen, your eye, etc.)? And how would that possibly be different than using your hand?

Comment: The wave pattern happens because there was no interaction before the photons have reached my screen.  But if my friend on Earth interacts with his entangled counterparts with his hand, before mine (or his) pass through our double-slit masks, I will expect to see that entangled stream of photons to act in a classical manner (slit-ey).  Then when he moves his hand out of the way, I expect they will pass through my slit mask, (and his) in a superposition, (as if through both slits at the same time,) because of the interaction with his hand.

Comment: Please see my answer to your question below. I would like to also point out that with entanglement, there is never a difference in observable outcomes when the measurement order is changed. There is no (demonstrable) sense of causal direction in these cases, although many/most QM/QFT interpretations assume one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple explanation for this scenario: Neither the Mars scientist nor the Earth scientist will ever see an interference pattern!

The reason is also simple: Entangled photons do not produce such a pattern because they do not have the necessary coherence properties.  The reasons are somewhat complicated (having to do with orthogonal paths), but you will be able to see more detail from this reference from a recent Nobel winner:

[Experiment and the foundations of quantum physics](https://courses.washington.edu/ega/more_papers/zeilinger.pdf) (1999)

See page S290, figure 2. This is exactly the scenario you propose.  From the associated text: "*Will we now observe an interference pattern for particle 1 [labeled a] behind its double slit?  ... Formally speaking, the states |a> and |a'> again cannot be coherently superposed because they are entangled with the two orthogonal states |b> and |b'>.*

To make these photons produce interference, you must place a single slit in front of the apparatus to create the necessary coherence.  That ends the entanglement, so now there is no longer the connection you intended.

Comment: Fantastic!  This finally makes sense!  I've been losing sleep on it, as there seemed to be a contradiction there, but the decoherence in the entanglement solves it!